# C++ seems to be turning my hex insignificant zeros into Fs

Tags: c++

I'm building out a class that takes in an array of hex values, stores them in a private property, and then will bring the

```
#include <iostream>

class RFIDData {
public:
    static const uint8_t idLength = 10;

private:
    int idArray[idLength] = {0};
    uint8_t currentIndex = 0;

public:
    void addIdElement(char element) {
        this->idArray[this->currentIndex] = element;
        this->currentIndex++;
    }
    void printArray() {
        for (uint8_t i = 0 ; i < idLength; i ++){
            std::cout << std::hex << this->idArray[i];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};

int idArray[] = {0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff, 0x00, 0x11};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    RFIDData rfid;

    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        rfid.addIdElement(idArray[i]);
    }
    rfid.printArray();
}
```

The problem that I'm running into is that when I step through the code and look at the private property values as they get added to the array the numbers are being stored with F's in place of the insignificant 0s in number and I'm not sure why.

e.g. the hex value `0xaa` is being stored as `0xffffffaa`.

[image: Example image showing the oddity]

I'm def green to c++ and trying to learn it. I'm sure it's something that I'm misunderstanding, just looking for a point in the right direction.

Comment: The `char` type is probably signed on your platform.

Comment: Ah! yeah I missed the char when I was switching the types I was using. I changed the `char` to an `int` and it works as expected. Thanks for the help :clap:

Comment: "Second pair of eyes" to the rescue.  ;-)

Comment: 100% :) Always comes in handy!

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz You can either answer or remove your question without any harm now.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Would be better if people answered in the correct place so that we get _a Q&A_ (gasp!) rather than a chatroom-like discussion that helped only one person then got removed from the web.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether `char` is signed or unsigned depends on your platform and toolchain, but it is often signed. A signed `char` initialised with the expression 0xAA, which happens when passing your `int`s into `addIdElement`, holds the value -86 (technically this is not guaranteed, but it follows from common two's complement implementations and compilers not wanting to do more work than necessary).

Conversion of this value back to a 32-bit `int` (`idArray`) tries to maintain the value -86, resulting in 0xFFFFFFAA. This is [sign extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension).

You may wish to specifically store `unsigned char`s so that your values and conversions are all unambiguously what you intended. In the below example I pull it out into its own type alias named `IdType`, to ensure consistency throughout your code:

```
#include <iostream>

class RFIDData {
public:
    using IdType = uint8_t;
    static const IdType idLength = 10;

private:
    IdType idArray[idLength] = {0};
    IdType currentIndex = 0;

public:
    void addIdElement(const RFIDData::IdType element) {
        this->idArray[this->currentIndex] = element;
        this->currentIndex++;
    }
    void printArray() {
        for (IdType i = 0 ; i < idLength; i ++){
            std::cout << std::hex << (unsigned int)this->idArray[i];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};

RFIDData::IdType idArray[] = {0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff, 0x00, 0x11};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    RFIDData rfid;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        rfid.addIdElement(idArray[i]);
    }
    rfid.printArray();
}

// Output: aabbccddeeff01100
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d5d3309909832836))

Notice that I also had to apply a cast when inserting the ID value to `std::cout`, since `uint8_t` is often `unsigned char` and the IOStreams part of the standard library treat these specially (or, rather, they *don't* treat them specially by lexically converting your numbers to their ASCII representation).

Comment: Wow thank you for this fantastic explanation of what was happening!! As someone still fresh to c++ having this kind of detailed explanation of what was happening and why is super helpful. Thanks!